# Fetch table of contents from html page in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, nsarray, epub

I am new to iPhone developer,

I made epub reader for my application, in which i want to fetch all the value of `<text>` tag from my local `.html` page and i want to store it in my array.

**For eg:**
This is my `toc.html` file, from this file i want to fetch all the value of `<text>` tag,

```
<navMap>
    <navPoint class="chapter" id="navpoint-1" playOrder="1">
        <navLabel>
           <text>Cover</text>
        </navLabel>
      <content src="Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight/OEBPS/first.html"/>
   </navPoint>

     <navPoint class="chapter" id="navpoint-2" playOrder="2">
        <navLabel>
          <text>News</text>
        </navLabel>
      <content src="Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight/OEBPS/1.html"/>
   </navPoint>

    <navPoint class="chapter" id="navpoint-3" playOrder="3">
       <navLabel>
          <text>Report</text>
       </navLabel>
      <content src="Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight/OEBPS/2.html"/>
    </navPoint>

    <navPoint class="chapter" id="navpoint-4" playOrder="4">
       <navLabel>
          <text>Economy Update</text>
       </navLabel>
      <content src="Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S 2/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight 26 April - K S/Morning Insight/OEBPS/3.html"/>
    </navPoint>

<navMap>
```

finally my array should have:

```
array at 0: Cover
array at 1: News
array at 2: Report
array at 3: Economy Update
```

**EDIT:**

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath:(BOOL)forSave {
    NSLog(@"Path of my file=%@",TOC);
    return TOC;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    TOCArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath:FALSE];
    NSData *response = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:response options:0 error:nil];

    NSArray *navPoints = [[[doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"navMap"] lastObject] elementsForName:@"navPoint"];

    for (GDataXMLElement *m in navPoints)
    {
        NSArray *navLabel = [m elementsForName:@"navLabel"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *e in navLabel)
        {
            NSArray *text = [e elementsForName:@"text"];
            [TOCArray addObject:[text objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<[TOCArray count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Toc array=%@",[TOCArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

}
```

My log Shows: `Path of my file=/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D414BC19-C005-4D93-896D-A6FB71DE4D21/Documents/UnzippedEpub/toc.ncx`

but my array is still null.

here is my `toc.ncx` file http://www.mediafire.com/?4r883s80he23cua

**NEW EDIT**

```
2012-07-23 16:07:50.522  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96480: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Cover</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.522  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96610: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>News</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.523  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96730: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Report</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.523  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96850: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Economy Update</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.524  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96970: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Other Factors</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.524  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96aa0: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Result Update</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.525  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96bc0: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Result Update (Continued)</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.526  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96ce0: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Trends in NIM</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.526  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96e00: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Key Stats</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.527  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a96f40: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Result Update</text>"}
2012-07-23 16:07:50.527  iBook [2105:fe03] Toc array=GDataXMLElement 0x6a97060: {type:1 name:text xml:"<text>Disclaimer</text>"}
```

Comment: Tried HTML parsing or XML parsing?

Comment: Thats great.. What was the output you got!!

Comment: something unexpected, do you know any tutorial or logic to implement this ?

Comment: http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/

http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/12/parsing-xml-files.html

Comment: Dude my file is already parsed at my simulator path, i want values inside tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some xml parsing for an app using `GData` & `TouchXML`..

Create an array to hold values.

Assuming your call to service returns `NSData` stored in response. Create a `GDataXMLDocument` object from it.

```
- (NSArray*)textArrayFromNCX
{
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

    // get the toc.ncx from documents folder
    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    docPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UnzippedEpub"];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"toc" ofType:@"ncx" inDirectory:docPath];

    // init the xml document
    NSData *response = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:response options:0 error:nil];

    // loop through the elements
    NSArray *navPoints = [[[doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"navMap"] lastObject] elementsForName:@"navPoint"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *m in navPoints)
    {
        NSArray *navLabel = [m elementsForName:@"navLabel"];
        for (GDataXMLElement *e in navLabel)
        {
            NSArray *text = [e elementsForName:@"text"];
            [values addObject:[[text lastObject] stringValue]];
        }
    }

    return values;
}
```

the `GData` Library returns array even if there is only one tag/element in actual xml. Inner loop only runs once per outer loop's iteration.

To learn how to integrate the library visit

http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

Comment: have you tried debugging to determine if the outer loop is running or not ??

Comment: try with this line instead `NSArray *navPoints = [[[doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"navMap"] lastObject] elementsForName:@"navPoint"];`

Comment: please answer it, i think you are very much near to my answer.

Comment: do this `[TOCArray addObject:[[text objectAtIndex:0]] stringValue];`

Comment: do you know how to find path a of file called `toc.ncx` in document directory ? in my document directory there are lots of folder, `toc.ncx` file will be inside one of the folder.

Comment: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"toc" ofType:@"ncx" inDirectory:DIR];` will return the path as string

Comment: you were doing fine... just add the stringValue method call as I suggest in previous comment